# Unable to resolve path to module 'react-native-screens' (ESLint)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Got this lint error in my VS Code:

> Unable to resolve path to module
>   'react-native-screens'.eslint(import/no-unresolved) module
>   "react-native-screens"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install 3 more libs **react-native-gesture-handler**, **react-native-reanimated**, and **react-native-screens** in order to work with navigation.

Run this code :

```
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens
```

For more information visit - [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project)

If you have the only issue with screens package install only that dependency

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @DeSilva glad it helps :) Read the documentation properly before you install